# Make element of class adressable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several Elements of the same class, I want to store each inside an array. Unfortunately in the array, the HTML is saved not the addressable jQuery-element. Below is just an example, I don't wan't to fade them out at once:

ERROR

```
undefined is not a function
```

HTML

```
<div class="a">1</div>  
<div class="a">2</div>  
<div class="a">3</div>
```

JS

```
var all = $('.a');
for (var i ; i < all.length; i++) {
    all[i].fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: `all[i]` will return just the pure DOM value, not `jQuery` object.

Comment: how do I get the jquery obj?

Comment: Are you looking to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dy4ht94e/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the DOM element that `all[i]` returns to a jQuery object:

```
var all = $('.a');

for (var i ; i < all.length; i++) {
    $(all[i]).fadeOut();
}
```

Or you can use jQuery's built-in method for accessing an element of a collection:

```
for (var i ; i < all.length; i++) {
    all.eq(i).fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an array if you're not concerned with the values? Can't you just do something like this:

```
$('.a').fadeOut();
```

Comment: Below was just an example, I don't wan't to dade them out at once:

Comment: How will you know which ones to fade out then?

Comment: its not about fade out

Comment: I know, but what you have now is an over-complicated way of targeting any class with `a`, but what are you going to do to target specific ones?

Answer (score 0):

Use `each` funtionality

```
$('.a').each(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
})
```

jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/qmryh9zb/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using each in jQuery:

```
var all = $('.a');


all.each(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

repro: http://jsfiddle.net/48vcafq8/